# Sails JS Send TCP

Tags: node.js, sails.js, tcp

Can sails JS communicate via TCP(socket) to server  ? Which library can I used ? like framework [action hero](http://www.actionherojs.com/) 
Can use 3 way to communicate like http, TCP and webscoket

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js can already handle TCP sockets vis the sockets.io library. See this example on github from the Sails.js creator:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/167

Comment: maybe this question its mean implementation sails js using TCP  not web socket

Comment: ohh sory i think @masadizainul right , this question is pure TCP not websocket  , but thanks you mr VladNeacsu :D